# What is the importance of mod_rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite, shared-hosting

If my hosting provider does not provide mod_rewrite mode. What thing will get effect on my wordpress?

I bought a hosting, they claim they does not provide it. I have installed WP and the web is running. I dont know what features I am missing.

The output of following command does not have mod_rewrite anywhere.

```
<? php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I put following contents in my .htaccess file. And mydomain.com/google.html redirect to google.com.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect /google.html http://www.google.com
```

That means mod_rewrite is working? And my hosting representative does not know this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Redirect` directive is part of Apache's [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html), not `mod_rewrite`.

`mod_rewrite` enables "pretty" permalinks, ie: `http://yourdomain.com/a-post-title/` rather than "ugly" permalinks ie:`http://yourdomain.com/?p=99`.

WordPress will operate just fine without mod_rewrite and pretty permalinks, it's just not as attractive or SEO friendly.

Comment: My website has this URL http://yansrhr.org/celebrations-of-international-year-of-youth/. And it means mod_rewirte is working in that server? Here is phpinfo page. http://yansrhr.org/phpmyinfo.php

Comment: @Tahir Akram - mod_rewrite is an Apache webserver module, not part of PHP, it won't show up in phpinfo. add `RewriteEngine on` to an htaccess file in a directory and then load that directory in your browser. If you don't get a 500 server error, then mod_rewrite is enabled. It would appear that it is though, if you're using pretty permalinks.

Comment: I used these lines in htaccess. RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^joomla\.html http://www.joomla.org/? [R=301,L] and it do redirect. Hosting guy does not know this.